# How to write letters with a circumflex?

Tags: math-mode

I want to write a theorem with letter `G`, which has over `^` it. I tried `$G^{\^}$`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: `\hat{G}` .....

Comment: Since `G` is uppercase, maybe `$\widehat{G}$`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks David it works well! You can write it as an answer.

Comment: @cfr I commented yes but deleted comment as I think not, the previous question and the accepted answer there are for getting `^` _not_ as an accent over a letter.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Perhaps I don't understand. I thought that the `$\hat{a}$` was exactly analogous to `$\hat{G}$` and that `$\widehat{abc}$` there was analogous to `$\widehat{G}$` here (maths). Similarly, `\^a` there seems analogous to `\^{G}` here (text) except that it might be better to use the curly brackets. That is exactly what I think of as a to bach accent i.e. a circumflex. You might be right about the question, though.

Comment: @cfr the last bit of the table does show accent usage but the actual question and most of the answer relate to getting the character on its own `\^{}` or `\textasciicircumflex` or `\verb|^|`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm really not bothered either way. To me, it is a duplicate but if others don't think so, that's fine. (I think the question is rather unclear which is why the answer is quite comprehensive.)

Comment: @review queue: I found this question today and I think it is not a duplicate of the linked question, because this question asks for accented letters and the other question asks for the `^`symbol in isolation, which is a quite different question with rather different answers as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

TeX distinguishes text accents (usually with single symbol names like `\^`) from math accents (usually with multi-letter names like `\hat`) so:

**In math:**

```
$\hat{G}$
```

or perhaps

```
$\widehat{G}$
```

**In text:**

```
\^{G}
```

Or if you specify a suitable input encoding such as `utf8` then you could just type the letter directly in text as

```
Ĝ
```